# How to make disabled TextBoxes selectable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a WPF application that contains telerikRadDataForms with the usual sort of controls, TextBlocks, TextBoxes, a number of telerik:RadGridViews, etc.

These forms may be displayed in read-only or can be editable. My problem is that my users want to be able to select, then copy to the clipboard, text that is displayed in the TextBoxes, when the forms are in read-only mode, and the controls are disabled.

The problem is that the textboxes aren't selectable, and hence the users can't copy the text that is in them.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do they need to be both readonly *and* disabled? Not sure if the `GotFocus` event fires while they're disabled, but if it does, can you just programatically set the `Text` property to the clipboard if so? If not there perhaps a `MouseClick` or `MouseDown` event?

Comment: I'm not sure that they are. Are you suggesting that if they were readonly, but not disabled, they'd be selectable?

Comment: The default behavior of `ReadOnly` still allows the control to be selectable and you can highlight text to copy it, yes. You just can't modify the text in it.

Comment: right but visually they are different. enabled has background color changes on mouse enter and also has regular font color compared to disabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the text to be selectable but read only, you can accomplish this by setting .ReadOnly to be true, rather than disabling the TextBoxes.